# Getting error 403 with axios while trying to fetch 'title' with jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio

I am trying to scrape title off website with axios and cheerio

This is my function:

```
async function getWebsiteInfo(uniqueId, req, res) {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');

    axios.get(req.body.url)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const scrapedata = $('title').first().text();
            console.log(scrapedata);
            var object = {
                "uuid": uniqueId,
                "url": req.body.url,
                "info": scrapedata
            }

            addToDatabase(object, res);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Anything I can do to not get an error 403?

Comment: website you are trying to access is not allowing you scrape, perhaps you need to login or something?

Comment: I tried with logging in but still dosnt work any way I can go around the "firewall" of websites that block web scrapers? @ShivamSood

Comment: You probably need to send some headers.

Comment: What kind of headers can I add with axios?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the headers your browser sends in the network panel and try sending that:

[image]